# random.sample in Python 3 (jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, scipy, jupyter-notebook

When using Canopy I can do

```
from scipy import *
import pylab as py
import random

aa = random.sample(arange(1,4,0.5),1)
```

whereas in the Jupyter notebook it complaints with the following:

```
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-e33979a68ee1> in <module>()
----> 1 cc = random.sample(arange(1,4,0.5), 1)

/u/rscratch/bm485/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/random.py in sample(self, population, k)
309             population = tuple(population)
310         if not isinstance(population, _Sequence):
--> 311             raise TypeError("Population must be a sequence or set.  For dicts, use list(d).")
312         randbelow = self._randbelow
313         n = len(population)

TypeError: Population must be a sequence or set.  For dicts, use list(d).
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: please list all your imports. Also prefer `import numpy as np` over `from numpy import *` - The latter import may shadow other imports.

Comment: I edited the question and included the imports @cel

Comment: `np.random.choice(np.arange(1,4,0.5), 1)` works, so does `random.choice(np.arange(1,4,0.5))`, from `scipy import *`  implicity pulls `numpy.random` into your name space.

Answer (score 2):

Please avoid star imports, wherever possible. It is often not clear what you actually imported and shadowed in the end.

```
import random
from scipy import *
print(random)
```

Gives:

```
<module 'numpy.random' from '/Users/ch/miniconda/envs/sci34/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/random/__init__.py'>
```

Whereas

```
from scipy import *
import random
print(random)
```

prints:

```
<module 'random' from '/Users/ch/miniconda/envs/sci34/lib/python3.4/random.py'>
```

Takehome message:

Prefer `import scipy as sp` or better `from scipy import <subpackage>` to avoid shadowing your random function. Thanks @ev-br for the remark.

---

If you are dealing with numpy's ndarrays, prefer the methods in `numpy.random` over the counter parts in python's random module. The issue you see here is that python and numpy have a different definition what a sequence is. For more details see the discussion here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2776

What you want is probably [`np.random.choice`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html#numpy-random-choice):

```
numpy.random.choice(a, size=None, replace=True, p=None)
```

Comment: There is no reason to do `import scipy as sp` even. Do `from scipy import subpackage or  `from scipy.subpackage import something`.

Comment: REMOVED
EDIT: Bad advice, apparently the documentation stating `import scipy as sp` has been depricated and recommended for removal, since the subpackages are not automatically loaded with scipy, meaning `sp.integrate` would raise an AttributeError.

Comment: @cel, while this answer makes a good point, is this causing the `TypeError`? The code in the question runs fine for me in Python 2.7 on Windows 7.

Comment: @o_o, good point, I think the underlying issue is actually https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2776

Comment: @cel, that looks about right. I'd imagine that explicitly converting to a list would solve the issue, but I don't have a Python 3.X installation to test it out on.